# CustomTkinter icons for app (with Pyinstaller)

Tags: python, filesystems, pyinstaller, native, customtkinter

I have created a small Python native app. Currently it is in the form of a folder with some python and other types of files and other folders with again some files, maybe Python or other types. Now I have one python file, that can call all other python files and functions. So, there is one main file. Since this is a GUI app, there had to be one file, the main GUI file. The only help I need is creating a logo for the executable file.
I did use the "**app.iconbitmap("path/to/logo.ico")**" but apparently, I have to put the icon file in the path. The problem is that the executable has to be a single file (pretty much obvious). So, how can I even send the icon file with it? I mean to send more than 1 file together, I have to bundle them in a folder. But the executable is one file. Can someone help me here? Thak you.